# Add one extra line break in a text in php

Tags: php

I want to change Text1 to Text2.

**Text1**

```html
Test1 is here<br>Now comes Test2<br>Then test 3<br><br>Thats it.
```

**Text2**

```
Test1 is here<br><br>Now comes Test2<br><br>Then test 3<br><br><br>Thats it.
```

i.e; add extra 'breakline' tag to the existing one in a string.

I tried it with preg_replace but can't figure it the way I wanted.

My Try -

```html
preg_replace('/(?:(?:<br>)\s*)/s', "<br><br>", $posttext)
```

Comment: and where is your php script exactly?

Comment: @davejal added above just now

Comment: You don't need any of the capture groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$text = preg_replace('/((<br>(\s+)?)+)/', '$1<br>', $text);
```

If you don't want to allow for newlines and spaces try:  `/((<br>)+)/`

Comment: It converts 1 to 2 breaks  buts fails for 2 to 3 breaks

Comment: Edited to fix and allow for newlines and spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
preg_replace('/((?:<br>)+)\s*/s', "$1<br>", $posttext);
```

This captures a sequence of `<br>` tags, optionally followed by whitespace, and then adds one more after them.

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/jxSASx)

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
$text1 = "Test1 is here<br>Now comes Test2<br>Then test 3<br><br>Thats it.";
$text2 = substr($text1,0,strripos($text1,"<br>")) ."<br>" . substr($text1,strripos($text1,"<br>"));
```

Comment: It converted 2 breaks to 3 but failed to convert 1 to 2.