# Remove one extra line break in a text in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

My question is exactly opposite to [this one i added last night](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33784682/add-one-extra-line-break-in-a-text-in-php) .
Need to remove the last br tag.

**Input:**

```
Test1 is here<br><br>Now comes Test2<br><br>Then test 3<br><br><br>Thats it.
```

**Output**

```
 Test1 is here<br>Now comes Test2<br>Then test 3<br><br>Thats it.
```

My try:

```
preg_replace("[((?:<br>)+)]","",$posttext)
```

It removes all breaks.

Comment: The output is
Test1 is here<br>Now comes Test2<br>Then test 3<br><br>Thats it.
or
Test1 is here<br>Now comes Test2<br>Then test 3<br>Thats it.

Comment: @faressoft o/p needed is  Test1 is here<br>Now comes Test2<br>Then test 3<br><br>Thats it.

Comment: That deleted answer would have almost worked - just needed to move the `+` into the parentheses : `/(<br>+)<br>/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can substitute

```
<br><br>(?!<br)
```

to `<br>`

```
preg_replace('/<br><br>(?!<br)/', "<br>", $posttext);
```

The [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) will prevent to match any more `<br>`

[See demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/gX4tR3/1)

Comment: just to mention, if you have whitespace in between, use `/<br>\s*<br>(?!\s*<br)/` [like this](https://regex101.com/r/yK3gN1/1).

Answer (score 0):

Feast your eyes on this hahaha

If Preg replace doesn't work...

```
// cuts off one <br> as high as whatever $i is at

$string = "Test1 is here<br><br>Now comes Test2<br><br>Then test 3<br><br><br>Thats it.";
$i = 10;

while($i > 0)
{
  $ii = 1;
  $brake = "<br>";
  $replace = "";
  while($ii < $i)
  {
   $brake .= "<br>";
   $replace .= "<br>";
   $ii++;
  }
$string = str_replace($brake,$replace,$string);
$i--; 
} 

 echo $string; // Test1 is here<br>Now comes Test2<br>Then test 3<br><br>Thats it.
```

PS: If theres no preg replace for this, it is usable albeit very inefficent.